# Inheritance in Android

Tags: android, inheritance, onclicklistener

I have two Activities in my app : Menu Activity and Main Activity.

> Here is MenuActivity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

    <LinearLayout 
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:background="#000">

        <TextView
            android:text="menu 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp"
         />

         <TextView
            android:text="menu 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp"
         />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> This is MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <include 
            layout="@layout/activity_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the OnClick Listener of menu1 and menu2 is defined in the `MenuActivity.java`.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

      TextView menu1, menu2;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

           menu1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu1);
           menu2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu2);

           menu1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu 1 clicked", 5000).show();
                }
           });

           menu2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu 2 clicked", 5000).show();
                }
           });

}
```

How do I inherit the OnClick listener in `MainActivity`. In short, my code in `MenuActivity` has to be used in various other activities, how do I use it? Please support with a piece of code and I have done plenty of searching but did not find anything relevant. I am new to Android, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a base class that you use in every activity where you use those menu buttons:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu1 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

        case R.id.menu2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu2 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then do this in your activies:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.menu1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.menu2).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

And in other activity you can do the same:

```
public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        findViewById(R.id.menu1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.menu2).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Just remember to include that menu layout in your activitys layout so you dont get null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't inherit OnClickListener you implement it!
Each activity implements its own `onClick()` which gives more flexibility to your code.

**EDIT** 
after reviewing your code you can simplify things which I believe it's what you want, you can implement OnClickListner to your activity and write one onClick method for all clickables in your activity here you can do this

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    TextView menu1, menu2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        menu1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu1);
        menu2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menu2);
        menu1.setOnClickListener(this);
        menu2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @override
    onClick( View view )
    {
        if (view == menu1)
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu 1 clicked", Toast.LONG).show();
        if (view == menu2)
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu 2 clicked", Toast.LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And it's better not to reference textviews if you won't use them

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        findViewById(R.id.menu1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.menu2).setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @override
    onClick( View view )
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.menu1)
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu 1 clicked", Toast.LONG).show();
        if (view.getId() == R.id.menu2)
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "menu 2 clicked", Toast.LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So If I have to include a menu bar (of say home, about us etc) in all activities, do I need to write the code for onclicklistener in all activities?

Comment: Yes, but you can write only one onClick per activity I;ve attached some code

Comment: You can simply create one class which implements OnClickListener interface and pass it in all of your activities to the views you want

Comment: You can do what @kjurkovic suggest but it's a bad practice you'll get a headache when modifying the code

Comment: thats true. it is a bad practice, but he did ask how to use one listener in all activities.

Comment: You don't want to learn bad habbits :) as a beginner you need good guidelines, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit the click listeners of Menu Activity in Main activity. Each activity has its own click listeners.  Although **you can make a general method** to perform some task and call that method from Both Activities but cannot inherit it like this way.